# how to get array's data in a blank array if condition is true using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-database

I have an array :

```
$stu_result( [exam_type] => 1 [subject_id] => 5 [converted_mark] =>5.00[student_id] => 186 [sub_name] => maths)
```

and its length is 15.
I want to match exam type and store sub_name and converted marks in a blank array. I tried this code :

This is my code tried so far

```
$result_exam1 = array();
foreach($stu_result as $result_temp){
 if($result_temp['exam_type'] == 1){
            $result_exam1['converted_mark'] = $result_temp['converted_mark'];
            $result_exam1['sub_name'] = $result_temp['sub_name'];
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the error? and which array data in $stu_result ?

Comment: in $result_exam1 store only last index data but i want to store all data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Note : `$stu_result`  should be a multidimensional array to loop and use `key value` feature of foreach loop to get all data like this :*

```
$result_exam1 = array();
foreach($stu_result as $key => $result_temp)
{
   if($result_temp['exam_type'] == 1)
   {
       $result_exam1[$key]['converted_mark'] = $result_temp['converted_mark'];
       $result_exam1[$key]['sub_name'] = $result_temp['sub_name'];
   }
}
print_r($result_exam1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I flushed out the entire array for $stu_result.  Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<?php
$stu_result = [
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 5,  "converted_mark" => 5.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 6,  "converted_mark" => 4.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 7,  "converted_mark" => 5.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 8,  "converted_mark" => 3.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 9,  "converted_mark" => 4.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 10, "converted_mark" => 3.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 11, "converted_mark" => 4.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 12, "converted_mark" => 5.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 13, "converted_mark" => 4.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 14, "converted_mark" => 5.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 15, "converted_mark" => 2.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 1, "subject_id" => 16, "converted_mark" => 1.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 2, "subject_id" => 17, "converted_mark" => 5.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "not maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 2, "subject_id" => 18, "converted_mark" => 2.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "not maths"),
  array("exam_type" => 2, "subject_id" => 19, "converted_mark" => 5.00, "student_id" => 186, "sub_name" => "not maths"),
];
$result_exam1 = array();
foreach($stu_result as $result_temp){
  if($result_temp['exam_type'] == 1){
    $row = array( //create an array, with two values and map the values
      "converted_mark" => $result_temp['converted_mark'],
      "sub_name"  => $result_temp['sub_name']
    );
    $result_exam1[] = $row; //append to the array
  }
}
var_dump($result_exam1);
?>
```